# Debugging an llvm pass with gdb

Tags: debugging, llvm

Is it possible to debug an llvm pass using gdb? I couldn't find any docs on the llvm site.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Build LLVM in non-release mode (the default). It takes a bit longer than a release build, but you can use gdb to debug the resulting object file.

One note of caution: I had to upgrade my Linux box to 3GB of memory to make LLVM debug mode link times reasonable.

Comment: But can I debug an llvm pass? LLVM passes are usually run using opt so I don't know how to use gdb to run it. Can you tell me the command?

Comment: You can run e.g. "gdb /usr/local/bin/opt" and type "run <your command line>".

Answer (score 7):

First make sure LLVM is compiled  with debug options enabled, which is basically the default setting. If you didn't compile LLVM with non-default options then your current build should be fine.

All LLVM passes are run using LLVM's `opt` (optimizer) tool.  Passes are compiled into shared object files, i.e., `LLVMHello.so` file in `build/lib` and then loaded by the `opt` tool.  To debug or step through the pass we have to halt LLVM before it starts executing the `.so` file because there is no way to put a break point in a shared object file. Instead, we can put a break in the code *before* it invokes the pass.

We're going to put a breakpoint in `llvm/lib/IR/Pass.cpp`

Here's how to do it:

1. Navigate to build/bin and open terminal and type `gdb opt`. If you compiled llvm with the debug symbols added then gdb will take some time to load debugging symbols, otherwise gdb will say `loading debugging symbols ... (no debugging symbols found)`.
2. Now we need to set a break point at the `void Pass::preparePassManager(PMStack &)` method in `Pass.cpp`. This is probably the first (or one of the first) methods involved in loading the pass. 
   You can do this by by typing `break llvm::Pass::preparePassManager` in terminal.
3. Running the pass. I have a bitcode file called `trial.bc` and the same `LLVMHello.so` pass so I run it with

   ```
   run -load ~/llvm/build/lib/LLVMHello.so  -hello < ~/llvmexamples/trial.bc > /dev/null
   ```

   gdb will now stop at `Pass::preparePassManager` and from here on we can use step and next to trace the execution.

Comment: Hi, I think I did not add debug symbols while building LLVM. Can I still use gdb for debugging? Will that have any limitations on debugging?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Following Richard Penningtons advice  + adding backticks works for me:

```
gdb /usr/local/bin/opt
```

then type

```
run `opt -load=/pathTo/LLVMHello.so  -hello < /pathTo/your.bc > /dev/null`
```

Note: I would have commented, but couldn't (missing rep.)